# Random Non-White Colors That Look Okay As Background for Black Text

Tags: language-agnostic, colors, background-color

I'd like to generate random, non-white colors using hue, saturation and brightness that can be used as a background for black text. I've created a generator for random colors, but when I scan the numbers, I can't see any clear pattern in the colors that look too dark.

**How can I generate random non-white background colors for black text?** Feel free to answer with code or pseudo-code, but it's definitely not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only generate colors with high brightness values - for example, if you were using the range 0-255 for each of {H,S,V}, you'd generate H in [0,255], S in [0,255], V in [168,255]. That should give you colors that are bright enough. You may want to restrict saturation as well (e.g. S in [0,192]), since black on full-bright, full-saturation colors may not be very readable.

You'll probably need to play with the values to get ranges that will give you usable colors.

Comment: I'll give it a go, but I'm beginning to suspect that there are interaction effects between the three nums

Comment: @Yar: Hmm, the gamut of a computer screen is indeed limited, if I understand this illustration correctly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamut I don't really know how to scale the three values to get more usable colors - this simple hack was enough for my limited needs.

Comment: just tried it, it actually doesn't look bad. I'll hold out for a more interesting answer, but it's quite good, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know color theory, but you can try randomly generating the 3 components in RGB (xxx,xxx,xxx) in a way that the sum of the components is greater than X (X depends of the contrast you want), and the convert to HSB.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that [se dice "randomly"].

Comment: Your right, thank you for the correction. I corrected the text.

Comment: No problem. I want to try out your solution -- using RGB instead of HSV -- and if it works, I'll vote this up and accept it. Will get back here shortly

Comment: The problem is that 200 units of green are a **lot** brighter than 200 units of blue. That's why I believe you need a model like YUV's luminosity rather than bogus "brightness=R+G+B". If you want to skip the heavy reading, just define Y=(3*R+4*G+1*B)/8 and make sure Y is at least 200 or so.

Answer (score 1):

HSV and HSL are broken models than have nothing to do with perception. You should generate your colors in YUV space (also known as YCbCr) where the intensity (Y) channel is not simply R+G+B but rather models the perceptual intensities of red, green, and blue. A good starting point would be to try random Y values at least 200 and random U and V values between -50 and 50.